# Bash script string manipulation

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

So I have a array of file names, that contain some tar files,
So for example there are 2 file names in the array, `acceptance-tests-0.0.134.tar` and `grafana-9.3.2-debian-11-r11.tar`.
How to we write a bash command that gets us, `0.0.134` from the first but `9.3.2-debian-11-r11` from the second ?

I tried `{imageName##*-}` that gives me the correct answer for the first `0.0.134` but just `r11` for the second

Here is the list of the entire array, if someone needs it,

```
acceptance-tests-0.0.134.tar
alertmanager-0.25.0-debian-11-r4.tar
blackbox-exporter-0.23.0-debian-11-r10.tar
busybox-1.36.tar
cephcsi-v3.5.1.tar
csi-attacher-v3.4.0.tar
csi-node-driver-registrar-v2.4.0.tar
csi-provisioner-v3.1.0.tar
csi-resizer-v1.3.0.tar
csi-snapshotter-v4.2.0.tar
dashboard-test-0.0.134.tar
fluent-bit-2.0.8.tar
grafana-9.3.2-debian-11-r11.tar
graylog-5.0.2.tar
grm-test-0.0.134.tar
kube-state-metrics-2.7.0-debian-11-r9.tar
lrm-sim-test-0.0.134.tar
mongodb-6.0.4-debian-11-r0.tar
node-exporter-1.5.0-debian-11-r9.tar
opensearch-2.3.0.tar
pcs-sim-test-0.0.134.tar
postgresql-repmgr-15.1.0-debian-11-r22.tar
prometheus-2.41.0-debian-11-r5.tar
prometheus-operator-0.62.0-debian-11-r0.tar
sftp-5.1.5.tar
system-tests-0.0.134.tar
```

Comment: Are the filenames in an array or in a file, with one name per line?

Comment: How would you explain, with your own words and in plain English, what you want to achieve? What is the rule that tells which `-` is the last to remove? Once you'll have answered this, and checked that it works with all examples you have, coding will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a files=(
  acceptance-tests-0.0.134.tar
  grafana-9.3.2-debian-11-r11.tar
)

shopt -s extglob # enable extended pattern matching

for f in ${files[@]}; do
  f=${f##+([[:alpha:]-])}
  f=${f%.*}
  printf "$f\n"
done
```

Will produce:

```
0.0.134
9.3.2-debian-11-r11
```

Comment: OP may have not realized but it's very common for a pkg name to include digit chars (like `python3`).

Comment: @pynexj absolutely, you're right. I will leave my answer as is, since your own already offers a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ print gensub(/.*-(v?[0-9]+\..*).tar/,"\\1","g") }' <(printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}")

0.0.134
0.25.0-debian-11-r4
0.23.0-debian-11-r10
...

$ awk '{ printf "%s \n", $0; print gensub(/(.*)-(v?[0-9]+\..*).tar/,"\\1 ==> \\2","g") }' \
     <(printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}")

acceptance-tests-0.0.134.tar 
acceptance-tests ==> 0.0.134
alertmanager-0.25.0-debian-11-r4.tar
alertmanager ==> 0.25.0-debian-11-r4
blackbox-exporter-0.23.0-debian-11-r10.tar
blackbox-exporter ==> 0.23.0-debian-11-r10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

tarfiles=(  acceptance-tests-0.0.134.tar
            alertmanager-0.25.0-debian-11-r4.tar
            blackbox-exporter-0.23.0-debian-11-r10.tar
            busybox-1.36.tar
            cephcsi-v3.5.1.tar
            csi-attacher-v3.4.0.tar
            csi-node-driver-registrar-v2.4.0.tar
            csi-provisioner-v3.1.0.tar
            csi-resizer-v1.3.0.tar
            csi-snapshotter-v4.2.0.tar
            dashboard-test-0.0.134.tar
            fluent-bit-2.0.8.tar
            grafana-9.3.2-debian-11-r11.tar
            graylog-5.0.2.tar
            grm-test-0.0.134.tar
            kube-state-metrics-2.7.0-debian-11-r9.tar
            lrm-sim-test-0.0.134.tar
            mongodb-6.0.4-debian-11-r0.tar
            node-exporter-1.5.0-debian-11-r9.tar
            opensearch-2.3.0.tar
            pcs-sim-test-0.0.134.tar
            postgresql-repmgr-15.1.0-debian-11-r22.tar
            prometheus-2.41.0-debian-11-r5.tar
            prometheus-operator-0.62.0-debian-11-r0.tar
            sftp-5.1.5.tar
            system-tests-0.0.134.tar                        )

shopt -s extglob
for tf in "${tarfiles[@]}"; do
    name_ver=${tf%.tar}
    name=${name_ver%%-@(v[0-9]|[0-9])*}
    if [[ $name == "$name_ver" ]]; then
        printf 'ERROR: Cannot extract version from: %q\n' "$tf" >&2
    else
        ver=${name_ver#"$name"-}
        printf '%s => %s\n' "$tf" "$ver"
    fi
done
```

- `shopt -s extglob` enables "extended globbing" (including patterns like `@(v[0-9]|[0-9])`).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${var%pat}`, `${var%%pat}`, and `${var#pat}`.